# Overlapping buttons issue when screen is minimized CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I am making a website and I have content on my HTML page that are constructed and styled via CSS. My issue is that the buttons and other content such as headers and hyper links  start to overlap. what changes must I make or what should I add to prevent this overlapping. I will provide my content and button styles.

```
.content{
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
min-height: 0px;
}


button{
width: 150px;
padding: 15px 0;
text-align: center;
margin: 20px 10px;
border-radius: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
border: 2px solid #009688;
background: transparent;
color: lightblue;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}


 HTML:
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <HTML>
   <head>
   <title>GymBros - Your Fitness Guide</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="banner">
    <div class="navbar">
        <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://strengthlevel.com/one-rep-max- 
            calculator" target="_blank" rel="noopener 
            noreferrer">PR Calculator</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.fatcalc.com/rwl" 
            target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Calorie 
          Deficit Calculator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
       

        <div>
            <button id="legs"><span></span>LEGS</button>
            <button id="arm"><span></span>ARMS</button>
            <button id="core"><span></span>CORE</button>
            <button id="back"><span></span>BACK</button>
            <button id="chest"><span></span>CHEST</button>
            <button id="shoulder"><span></span>SHOULDERS</button>
            
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id = "quoteCircle">
        <p id="quoteText">Quotes</p>
    </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>



 </body>
 </html>
```

I messed with @media but I still couldn't pinpoint what the issue was and never resolved it.

Comment: Can you include the HTML, otherwise we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok i did what you asked of me

Comment: The overlap happens because you use `position:absolute`. This causes elements to be placed on top of each other. You can simply remove it to have `<div>` elements appear under each other.